# Coalescing has no effect on number of partitions in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is the code:

```
  val nouns = sc.textFile("/Users/kaiyin/IdeaProjects/learnSpark/src/main/resources/nouns")
  val verbs = sc.textFile("/Users/kaiyin/IdeaProjects/learnSpark/src/main/resources/verbs")
  val sentences = nouns.cartesian(verbs).take(10)
  sentences.foreach(println _)
  println(s"N partitions for nouns: ${nouns.partitions.size}")
  nouns.coalesce(10, true)
  println(s"N partitions for nouns after coalesce: ${nouns.partitions.size}")
```

Result:

```
N partitions for nouns: 2
N partitions for nouns after coalesce: 2
```

From spark 1.6.2 doc:

> Note: With shuffle = true, you can actually coalesce to a larger
>   number of partitions. This is useful if you have a small number of
>   partitions, say 100, potentially with a few partitions being
>   abnormally large. Calling coalesce(1000, shuffle = true) will result
>   in 1000 partitions with the data distributed using a hash partitioner.

But apparently `coalesce` has not effect at all in this case. Why?

Whole script is here: https://github.com/kindlychung/learnSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/RDDDemo.scala

Comment: Would I be correct to presume that nouns contains more than 2 items?

Comment: 1525 items according to `wc -l`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coalesce` doesn't modify RDD in place but returns a new RDD. Since you check number of partitions of the input RDD this an expected output.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100, 10)
val coalesced = rdd.coalesce(200, true)
coalesced.partitions.size
// Int = 200
```